# python using os.listdir and genfromtxt with multiple files

Tags: python, csv

its my first post, i just hope to explain my problem in detail.

Here, i am mixing CSV files by name.

```
path = "C:\\Data\\Files"
dir = os.listdir(path)
for i, j in itertools.combinations(dir, 2):
    if i[1:4] == j[1:4]:
        print(i, j)
```

My problem is than i wanna do this

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(dir, 2):
    if i[1:4] == j[1:4]:
       operando1 = np.genfromtxt(i, delimiter=",")
       operando2 = np.genfromtxt(j, delimiter=",")

       divisa1 = operando1[:, 0]
       divisa2 = operando2[:, 0]

       diff = np.empty([], dtype="float")
       diff = divisa1 - divisa2
```

My main problem is than genfromtxt doesn't work, i know than genfromtxt works fine when it write the path with the file but is there any solution for this?

One question more, if i save diff in a dictionary, how can i save the key with the name of the files?

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the full path unless your cwd is C:\\Data\\Files , `os.path.join(path, i)` etc.. Also saying *genfromtxt doesn't work* is not usually very useful, you should explain how it is not working. You can also group common files using a dict using `file_name[1:4]` as the key and appending the file names as value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  thank you, it works perfectly and yes, i always have to show the error. One question more, i am working without define a Class, when i am working in a method and call another, Python says 'name 'operaciones' is not defined', why?

Comment: without seeing the actual code it is hard to say